# ls to show only directory/filename and size

Tags: command-line, freebsd, ls, tcsh

First of all, this is not a duplicate of this: [Linux ls to show only filename date and size](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22218/linux-ls-to-show-only-filename-date-and-size)

Because I want to print actual directory name additionally.

I was always using this command:

```
ls -l | awk '{print $5, $9}'
```

to get the each file size and name.

But now, I need to print the file directory additionally. Like if the current directory is `/path/to/somewhere`, I want:

```
somewhere/file 1234
somewhere/other-file 4567
```

Instead of just

```
file 1234
other-file 4567
```

Is that possible?

Comment: What do you mean by the file directory? A full absolute path? The parent directory?

Comment: u want pwd in ur output?

Comment: @MatthewScharley Ofc. the parent directory.

Comment: If you add -F to ls it will 'classify' names, then directories will print with a trailing /, eg foo/ Unfortunately other files will also have classify chars added as well (executables have * appended to name).

Comment: Actually, you should [avoid parsing the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Imagine what would happen if say the username had a whitespace character in it.

Answer (score 5):

You mean like this, just prepending the current directory to each filename?

```
ls -l | awk '{printf("%s %s/%s\n", $5, ENVIRON["PWD"], $9); }'
```

Or something else?

---

OK, *apparently* what you want is

```
$ cd /some/path/to/somewhere
$ <insert command here>
somewhere/file1 size1
somewhere/file2 size2
...
```

Is *that* correct?

If so, the change you need (assuming a POSIX shell) is this:

```
ls -l | DIR=${PWD##*/} awk '{printf("%s/%s %s\n", ENVIRON["DIR"], $9, $5); }'
```

instead.

In `tcsh`, as your `Illegal variable name` error suggests you're using, you'd use:

```
ls -l | env DIR=$PWD:t:q awk '{printf("%s/%s %s\n", ENVIRON["DIR"], $9, $5); }'
```

instead.

---

If it *still* doesn't work, please describe your platform, shell, version of awk etc. in your question - the comment thread is getting pretty long and I'm running out of guesses :-)

Comment: It does actually print the full path like: `6452 /usr/local/data/pack_24022012/update.ent`

Comment: Yup, I'm just asking if that's what you want, or if you were asking for something else.

Comment: Okay, as I said, I want to just print the 'actual' (parent) directory name, where the command is executed at. Fe. I'm executing the `ls [..]` inside of the `/usr/local/data/something` then it will list the files this way: `something/file1.apx <size>` and so on... Hope you got me, in case if not, leave a comment back.

Comment: You do know that 'actual' isn't a recognised technical term, right? If it's hard to explain clearly, just show sample output in the first place (like you've now done in your comment)

Comment: Okay, sorry that I didnt explain this clearly. Here is what I get while running your edited command: `Illegal variable name.`

Answer (score 4):

In the spirit of "not parsing ls output", why not use `find`?:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -printf '%p\t%s\n'
```

(here assuming GNU `find` for its `-printf` extension).

Replace `.` with `"$PWD"` (or `$PWD:q` if using `tcsh`) if you want the full paths of the files. Note that contrary to `ls`, it includes hidden files and doesn't sort the list of files.

Comment: Seems like this is what OP wants: `find $(pwd) -maxdepth 1 -printf "%s\t%p%s\n"`

Comment: This is the simplest answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include the directory part of the file name in the `ls` output, include it on the command line.

```
ls -ld "$PWD"/* | awk '{print $5, $9}'
```

If you want to print a relative path, arrange to call `ls` from the right directory so as to print the relative path you want, e.g.

```
dir=$(dirname "$PWD")
cd .. && ls -ld -- "$dir"/* | …
```

Do be aware of the [pitfalls of parsing the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs): if a user name or a group name or a file name contains whitespace, that snippet spews out nonsense.

A reliable, but non-portable, way of listing file attributes in a custom format is [`stat`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=stat&sektion=1).

```
stat -f '%8z %R' -- *
stat -f '%8x %n' -- "$dir"/*
```

A slower but more flexible way of producing this output is to iterate over the files inside the shell.

```
for x in *; do
  printf '%8d %s\n' "$(wc -c <"$x")" "whatever/you/want/$x"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ du -b
```

and for human readable size:

```
$ du -bh
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you only need `ls`:

```
ls -sh1 /var/log/mysql/*
0 /var/log/mysql/mysqld.log
4.0K /var/log/mysql/mysqld.log-20140718
4.0K /var/log/mysql/mysqld.log-20140827
4.0K /var/log/mysql/mysqld.log-20140829
```

- `-s` print size of each file
- `-h` print human readable sizes
- `-1` print each file in a new line
- `*` wildcard globbing which "enables" printing the full path
- optional: `-S` sort by size
- optional: `-t` sort by time

Answer (score 0):

This is borrowed from what [Useless](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/14898/useless) has suggested [above](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/32573/29257):

```
/bin/ls -l | awk -v CUR_DIR=$(basename $(pwd)) '{ if ($1 != "total") {printf("%s/%s %s\n", CUR_DIR, $8, $5);} }'
```

This, however, filters the "total xyz" line. Note that output of `ls` might differ on different distributions. Mine shows file name in the 8th column (whereas Useless shows it as 9th column). Sample output is shown below:

```
ds/binary_search.py 1660
ds/growth.png 28262
ds/growth.py 1147
ds/heap.py 1277
ds/postfix.py 969
ds/prim.py 39
ds/queue.py 1188
ds/quicksort.py 2535
ds/QuickSortWeiss.class 2821
ds/QuickSortWeiss.java 3500
ds/sin-cos.py 401
ds/sin-cos-two.png 28509
ds/sorting.py 4997
```

One last point: it might be helpful to provide the exact location of `ls`. Otherwise, in the case that `ls` is aliased to something else, the output might again vary.

#### Update:

The above command doesn't seem to work on all systems, am not sure why. However, this one should work, I hope.

```
/bin/ls -l | awk  '{ if ($1 != "total") {printf("%s/%s %s\n", $(basename $(pwd)), $8, $5);} }' | awk '{ print $8, $9 }'
```

Comment: Getting 
`Illegal variable name.` message in bash...

Comment: Oh ok, I guess it was that `$PWD` thing. Please try the above code.

Comment: I do still get `Illegal variable name` message :/

Comment: Ohh...I'm not sure what's problem with your bash. However, try the above alternative. This should help you.

Comment: `awk: illegal field $(), name "pwd"
 input record number 2, file
 source line number 1
` ...

Comment: You should provide the version of your bash, Linux, and other related things here. It's difficult for anyone to solve your problem otherwise, I guess.

Comment: I'm using original bash from FreeBSD 8.2, it doesn't work on Debian 5.0 Lenny eighter, so why don't you test your code first , before posting it?:P

Comment: Seems to work perfectly with `mawk 1.2` on Debian 6, and `gawk 3.1` on Ubuntu 10.04; `bash 4.1` in both cases. I don't have access to other platforms -- hope someone could help you.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `tree` or `stat`:

```bsh
# tree --dirsfirst -a -C -i -h -F --du -L 1 ./

./
[   0]  Test/
[   0]  vcredist/
[3.0K]  .gitignore*
[1.1K]  LICENSE*
[1.3K]  LICENSE.rtf*
[ 17K]  SomeThing.sln
[8.5K]  README.md

  31K used in 19 directories, 5 files
```

The `--du` flag is supposed to get you the size of each directory, but not working on my distro.

```bsh
# stat --format '%s %N' *

0 './build'
0 './Examples'
1087 './LICENSE'
1343 './LICENSE.rtf'

# stat --printf '%s\t%N\n' *

0       'build'
0       'Examples'
1087    'LICENSE'
1343    'LICENSE.rtf'
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi the best simple answer is to use du -sh *
What this command does it is shows the file sizes in kilobytes, megabytes and GB and TB all with a list of the name of the folder or file in the directory.

Comment: this solution does not print dir and file name as requested in the question